# Why external JSX template fetched after Double Network Request?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I am exploring [reactjs](http://facebook.github.io/react/) but i am surprised to see this Double Network request for External JSX template(`loginform.js`).

where

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Awan Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

Hello Sir!

<script src="../../build/react.js"></script>
<script src="../../build/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" src="loginform.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and loginform.js

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
    var LoginForm = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
            return <form id="f_loginform" method="POST">
                    UserName:<input type="text"/>
                    Password:<input type="password"/>
                </form>;
        }
    });
    React.renderComponent(<LoginForm/>, document.body);
```

Is there any way that i can avoid this double request?

Please consider attached image for detail:

[image: Screenshot with Chrome-v30]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not obvious to me why Chrome insists on fetching the script when it sees the script tag `<script type="text/jsx" src="loginform.js"></script>`. I'd expect it to skip the request completely since it doesn't recognize the `type`.

However, the in-browser JSX transformer isn't designed for efficiency and should be avoided in production when you care about speed (and you should see a warning in your console to that effect). Instead, when packaging and minifying your JS, you should precompile your JSX files into raw JS which can be included like any other piece of JS code. For more info, see [Productionizing: Precompiled JSX](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#productionizing-precompiled-jsx) on the React site.